# Why the output is "p not defined"?

Tags: python-3.x

```
import socket              # Import socket module

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)         # Create a 
socket object

host = socket.gethostbyname("www.itsecgames.com")

global port

for port in range(0,1):
    try :
        connect = s.connect((host,port))
        print("Port [",port,"] : Connection accepted.")
        global p 
        p = port
    except :
        print("Port [",port,"] : Connection refused.")
w = p

print(w)
```

I got:

```
w = p
NameError: name 'p' is not defined
```

Comment: p = port had never had chance to run?

Comment: I doubt sockets are required to reproduce this. Build a [mcve].

Comment: What happens if you fix the `global port` clause to `global port,p`?

Comment: That is not the full output.

Comment: Try example in my answer after removing 0/0 - you will see at module level code will work. So outer scope argument here does not hold.

Answer (score 2):

The problem can only be reproduced [when `connect` throws](https://www.ideone.com/WlEw71).

That's because, in such a case, you never set `p`. Since you never set `p`, and it doesn't exist in the global scope until you do so, `w = p` is invalid.

Consider giving it some initial value, or skip the whole `w` thing unless the connection were established.

Specifically, in this case, the reason that your `connect` call throws is that you're trying to connect to a website on port 0. HTTP webpages are usually reachable on port 80.

Comment: Downvote why? This is (a) the cause of `except` being hit and (b) why that leads to the complained-about error. What more do you want?

Answer (score 2):

Globals are irrelevant here and in general should be avoided in Python. In simplified example one can clearly see that except-part leaves p undefined:

```
global port

for port in range(0, 1):
    try:
        #global p
        0 / 0
        p = port
    except:
        print("Port [",port,"] : Connection refused.")
w = p

print(w)
```

The cure is simple:

```
p = None
```

Before the loop.

More notes: range(0, 1) produces just one value.